# Login function of Auth not working with cakePhp-2.6

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.6

I have set up my website so only add and login are only accessible before the user log in. And when he log in, he is redirected to the home page.
But when the user tries to log in, the login page refreshes and it shows this message "Username or password is incorrect" which is from the action login of my controller.
I verified and it's "$this->Auth->login()" which is not working.

In my database, i used these fields for the user table: id, password, nom, prenom, username.

Here is the login function code from my controller UsersController:

```
public function login()
  {
     if ($this->request->is('post'))
     {
        if ($this->Auth->login())
          {
              return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
          }
         else
         {
              $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
         }
     }
  }
```

Here is the login view code:

```
<?php
   echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
   echo $this->Form->create('User');
   echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Votre pseudo: '));
   echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Votre mot de passe: '));
   echo $this->Form->end('Se connecter');
?>
```

Here is User model code:

```
<?php

   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
   App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

   class User extends AppModel
   {
      public $hasMany = array('Compte','ComptesUtilisateur');

      public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
         Security::setHash('md5');

         if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))
         {
            $passwordHasher= new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
         }

         return true;
      }
   }
?>
```

And here AppController.php code:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

   var $components = array(
      'Auth' => array(
         'authError' => "Etes-vous sûr(e) d'avoir l'autorisation pour y accéder?",
         'loginError' => "Votre pseudo ou votre mot de passe est incorrect",
         'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
         ),
         'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
         'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
         'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
               'fields' => array(
                  'username' => 'username',
                  'password' => 'password'
               ),
               'passwordhasher' => array(
                  'className' => 'Simple',
                  'hashType' => 'md5'
               )
            )
         )
      ),
      'Session'
   );

   public function beforeFilter()
   {
      $this->Auth->allow('login');
   }

   public function beforeRender()
   {
      $this->set('auth', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
   }
}
```

I searched the solution on forums but i found nothing.

Any indication?

Thanks,
Louberlu.

Comment: A friend of mine find a error. It's in the AppController. In the array, it's not passwordhasher but passwordHasher.